# Is "width" treated differently in IE and Mozilla?

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, yui

I am writing simple page with `autocomplete` text box feature.I have set `widht:87%` for input box and its working fine in mozilla but in IE first the text box expands while page is loaded and shrinks while suggestions are displayed.
Here is my code

```
<td valign="middle">  
<input id="myInput" name="ontFindNameMatch" type="text" maxlength="100" style="border:1px solid #7c9cba;width:87%;font-size:11px;" />
<br/>
<div id="myContainer" style="z-index:10;width:87%"> 
</div>
</td>
```

`myInput` is input text box and in `myContainer` autocomplete suggestions are displayed.I am using `YUI autocomplete`.
Image when page is loaded.
[image]
After suggestions are displayed
[image] 
In mozilla the width remains same.

**EDIT**

Got the solution. Thanks amadeus

```
<td valign="middle" >
<div id="autocomplete" class="yui-ac"> 
<input id="myInput" class="yui-ac-input" name="ontFindNameMatch" type="text" style="border:1px solid #7c9cba;font-size:11px;" /> 
<br/>
<div id="myContainer" class="yui-ac-container" style="z-index:100;"> 
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

~Ajinkya.

Comment: Does your HTML have a doctype declaration?

Comment: Yes. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: This would be easy to solve with a link to a live page. Could you provide one?

Comment: Sorry I cannot put it it live. Client restriction :(

Comment: @BoltClock,thirtydot: Any guess or suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the width attribute to from myInput and myContainer to td element.
Try removing maxlength.

Remove br element.

Do not style myInput and myContainer inline, but use
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_skinning.html

Comment: Its works like a charm :) You saved my life. Can you please tell me what was the exact problem ? Still not able to figure it out.

Comment: @Ajinkya: What was your solution?

Comment: Out for a coffee. Will post soon.

Comment: Updated my question with answer.